# Independent 'Find in Folders' history for Sublime Text 3 projects

Tags: sublimetext3

I work with `Sublime Text 3` on multiple different projects, and I noticed that the history of the `Where:` field on the 'Find in Files' feature's UI (available with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) shows the history from all my projects, so it often gets prefilled with a value that was used in a different project.

How can I make `Sublime` use a different history for the different projects I work on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symptom in the question only arises if you don't have workspace files for your projects, so when your projects are in fact only folders that you open with `Sublime`. If your projects already have workspace files, than they should use the history from their respective workspace files (and you can edit those files to remove elements from under the `where_history` key in that file - given that you don't have the project opened in `Sublime`).

So all you have to do is to create workspace files for your projects, and remove the unneeded entries from them:

- Open the project (folder) in `Sublime Text 3` you want to have a
  separate history for
- Create a `<projectname>.sublime-workspace` file for the project by
  clicking `Project`/`Save workspace as...` in the menu
- Close the project (it's important!)
- Edit the created file

  - Find the `find_in_files` key, and its `where_history` sub-key
  - You should see your global history there, remove all items or alternatively leave the items that are related to your project
  - Save the file
- Open the project in Sublime Text 3, now the 'Find in Files' history should be project specific

New history items will be added to your workspace file when you close the project, so the next time you open it, it will have the history from your last session, but it will not get mixed up with search history items from other projects.

Example workspace file excerpt:

```
...
"find_in_files":
{
    "height": 93.0,
    "where_history":
    [
        "/path/to/project/root",
        "/path/to/project/source/files"
    ]
},
...
```

Do that for all projects that need a separate history.